# Updating MVar Throws Exception

Tags: haskell

Given:

```
λ: >let x = Control.Concurrent.MVar.newMVar ""
λ: >:t x
x :: IO (MVar [Char])
```

I tried to call `putMVar`:

```
λ: >:t putMVar
putMVar :: MVar a -> a -> IO ()

λ: >:t x
x :: IO (MVar [Char])
```

yet it failed

```
λ: >x >>= \y -> putMVar y "foo"
:^?^?

*** Exception: thread blocked indefinitely in an MVar operation
```

Why did it fail and how can I update `x` with `"foo"` rather than `""`?

Comment: I think you create your new `MVar` with a value - you need to extract that value before you put one into it!

Comment: This is intended: the semantics of `MVar` is the one of a 1-position queue protected with a mutex. You create a full queue containing `""`. You can't queue anything else until you empty the queue first with `takeMVar`. Otherwise `putMVar` will wait for someone else to empty the queue first. In your case, GHC notices that noone can empty the queue, and triggers the exception instead of getting stuck forever (the runtime is trying to be kind, here, reporting the bug).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`x` is not an `MVar`. It is an action that creates an `MVar`, i.e. it's another name for `newMVar ""`.

`x >>= \y -> putMVar y "foo"` is an action that creates an `MVar` and names it `y`. It then tries to put `"foo"` in the `MVar`. However, `y` already contains `""`, so `putMVar` blocks. It doesn't simply block forever because `y` is a local variable in this action, meaning no one else has access to it and no readers exist. `putMVar` detects this situation (deadlock) and throws an exception instead.

What you should do instead is start with:

```
x <- newMVar ""
```

This makes `x` an `MVar`.

Then you can take the old value (`""`) out:

```
takeMVar x
```

And put a new value in

```
putMVar x "foo"
```

(`MVar` doesn't support replacing the existing value in one step; you first have to take it out, then put a new value in.)

Answer (score 6):

Let's look up the documentation:

> ```
> data MVar a
> ```
>
> An MVar (pronounced "em-var") is a synchronising variable, used for
>   communication between concurrent threads. It can be thought of as a a
>   box, which may be empty or full.

and

> ```
> newMVar :: a -> IO (MVar a)
> ```
>
> Create an MVar which contains the supplied value.

and

> ```
> putMVar :: MVar a -> a -> IO ()
> ```
>
> Put a value into an MVar. If the MVar is currently full, putMVar will
>   wait until it becomes empty.
>
> There are two further important properties of putMVar:
>
> putMVar is single-wakeup. That is, if there are multiple threads
>   blocked in putMVar, and the MVar becomes empty, only one thread will
>   be woken up. The runtime guarantees that the woken thread completes
>   its putMVar operation. When multiple threads are blocked on an MVar,
>   they are woken up in FIFO order. This is useful for providing fairness
>   properties of abstractions built using MVars.

melpomene's answer contains the correct explanation. I let my answer remain here for the cited documentation.